# Create variable to establish excel sheet based on day

Tags: python, datetime, environment-variables

Im looking to add an option to a menu that will create a workbook tab with the title of the current day.

Im running:

```
wb=load_workbook(/path/)
# Create sheet based on day
date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
wb.create_sheet(date)

#save changes
wb.save(filepath)
```

and im getting:

```
File "/path", line 39, in menu
date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")

NameError: name 'today' is not defined
```

any ideas?

UPDATE:
current code:

```
        from openpyxl import load_workbook
        import os
        import datetime 

        wb=load_workbook("C:/path/)

        # Create sheet based on day
        today = datetime.date.today()     # <-- Define the `today` object

        #create worksheet
        wb.create_sheet(today)

        #save changes
        wb.save(filepath)
```

results in:

File "C:/path/", line 93, in title
    m = INVALID_TITLE_REGEX.search(value)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

As the NameError suggests, the `today` object wasn't defined.

I've add a couple of lines to your code below, which should help.

```
            import datetime                     # <-- Ensure `datetime` module is imported
            wb=load_workbook(/path/)
            # Create sheet based on day
            today = datetime.datetime.now()     # <-- Define the `today` object
            date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
            wb.create_sheet(date)

            #save changes
            wb.save(filepath)
```